# geopandas.overlay() doesn't work in google colaboratory this return AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google

When I try to make an intersection between two Geodataframes in google colab, I get it the next error message:

[image]

This is my pace of code:

```
link1 = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=10OXg2zhFp9Dhxqz_4mXqw4R16_13VoMv'
wdir, id = link1.split('=')
id

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Forest_zone.geojson')
print('The files was downloaded')

forest_zone = gpd.read_file('Forest_zone.geojson')

link2 = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t5b5aUfVrOh3e5uBylmbVaXsBshc6l6f'
wdir, id = link2.split('=')
id

downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('Study_area.geojson')
print('The files was downloaded')

study_area = gpd.read_file('Study_area.geojson')

inter = gpd.overlay(forest_zone, study_area, how='intersection')
```

if you want to see all notebook for helping me, this is the link of my current notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kTba6gqc5yDj_a3AhgwOIV3LUXG18Frs

Comment: The error message indicates that the [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) module is not installed

Comment: Can you post the error as formatted text so it is searchable for users?

Comment: Yes I can, I make a few changes on this post, I hope that works for yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem of Google colad, but, as I said in my comment, you must install [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/).

```
warn("Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package `rtree`.")
```

Look at 
[Overlay Function from GeoPandas Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546775/overly-function-from-geopandas-not-working)

> To be able to use the overlay function you need more than just install geopandas, you need install rtree, but rtree is a wrapper to the C library libspatialindex. So to use rtree library you need to install [libspatialindex](https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex) C library.

In [GeoPandas: install](http://geopandas.org/install.html)

> Warning
>   When using pip to install GeoPandas, you need to make sure
>   that all dependencies are installed correctly.
>   ....
>   **[rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) does not provide wheels.**
>   ....

Therefore you cannot install rtree with pip and you must choose another method,  independently of GeoPandas ([Rtree installation](http://toblerity.org/rtree/install.html))

And

```
inter = gpd.overlay(forest_zone, study_area, how='intersection')
print(inter.head())
   st_area_sh      cod_dane  ...     departamen           geometry
0  717156560.907    73001    ...      TOLIMA  POLYGON ((-75.33499022858835 4.66015859992620...
1   1227.8963508    73001    ...      TOLIMA  POLYGON ((-75.27023446072464 4.443991322020056...
2   184060.36275    73001    ...      TOLIMA  POLYGON ((-75.18259468247429 4.379858423561434...
3  129158.354723    73001    ...      TOLIMA  POLYGON ((-75.29231944063352 4.471500289298558...
4  45861.4469718    73001    ...      TOLIMA  POLYGON ((-75.23275926314781 4.50074008924839,...
```

Comment: yes is very interesting your explain... but, when I use this code into google colab:             `!easy_install Rtree`
`!sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev`.                                         I still getting the error:                                                                           
`warn("Cannot generate spatial index: Missing package `rtree`.")`

Comment: Use the explications of  [Rtree installation](http://toblerity.org/rtree/install.html).: install  libspatialindex  first, then rtree

Comment: Thank you the explain it works. This is I notebook that I founded... do you think that the code was made in the right way... or you see any mistake? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N7i9zmOwVcUzd4eHWZux4p_WTBMZHi8C#scrollTo=rwh2MFYa98qA

Comment: If it works, no problem

Comment: As of 2022. I did a simple `pip install rtree` to clear the geopandas intersection error.